# IPv6 on Android with DHCPv6-based ISP

Tags: android, dhcp, ipv6, mikrotik, slaac

My ISP assigns IPv6 prefixes using DHCPv6. I know Android only supports SLAAC. Is there any way I can configure my router to provide Android devices with IPv6 Internet connectivity?

Comment: Log a support ticket with your phone's supplier.. or get a phone that does support DHCPv6?

complain to Google about it

Answer (score 2):

Your router should already provide slaac.
Your Android phone build its own addresses.

Comment: That does’t appear to be the case at the moment. How can I make a GNU/Linux computer precisely mimic Android’s behavior, so as to debug the router’s ability to provide SLAAC using its DHCPv6’ed address?

Comment: A router receives the prefix(WAN). Under normal circumstances the router uses the information to start its own router advertisement (radvd)  on the LAN. Depending on the configuration the router starts also a dhcpv6 server on LAN. Under Linux you can use for Networkmanager (with disabled dhcpv6) to emulate Android behavior. Use wireshark for all details.